# NullPointerException using DOMParser and selectSingleNode

Tags: xpath, dom4j

```
String url = "http://www.amazon.com/Classic-Starts-Great-Expectations/dp/1402766459/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1294405505&sr=1-1";

DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
parser.parse(url);

Document document = parser.getDocument();
DOMReader reader = new DOMReader();
org.dom4j.Document nhddoc = reader.read(document);

//book price
Node price = nhddoc.selectSingleNode("/HTML/BODY/DIV[2]/FORM/TABLE[3]/TBODY/TR/TD/DIV/TABLE/TBODY/TR/TD[2]/B");
System.out.println(price.getText().toString().trim());
```

the error i get is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at nekodom4j.Main.main(Main.java:44)
```

does the null pointer exception means no node was selected ?

Comment: One thing you're doing wrong is writing questions. This is barely even coherent.

Comment: at which step it failed?

Comment: If it was a DOM4J error, you'd have gotten an exception.  If you're asking "Is there a bug in DOM4J?", the emphatic answer is "no".  It's far more likely that you and your code have an issue.  If the parse succeeds, I'd recommend pretty printing the DOM Document and look at it.  A visual should help you confirm where your selection has gone wrong.

Comment: Do note that there could be differences between the DOM built by browsers and the one built by your API, mostly because **HTML spec mandatory** elements like `tbody` for `table`.

Comment: i used the method Dave Costa suggested and it appears that at a certain point in the path a whole part of the html dissapears. so it appears dom4j fails to parse the html. the elements that are missing are a couple of divs a hr and a table

Answer (score 1):

I have no particular idea what the cause of the problem might be, but the first thing I would do to debug it would be to walk the path one level at a time and see where it fails to return what you expect.

```
Node html = nhddoc.selectSingleNode("/HTML");
/* maybe print out some information about the Node just acquired */
Node body = html.selectSingleNode("/BODY");
```

etc...

Comment: my mistake: i thought that the html page parsed by dom4j was identical to the one displayed in firefox at original location. 

fix: i saved the parsed html page to hdd, opened with firefox and explored it with firebug.